# How can I restore folders from an external hard drive using my ubuntu computer?

Tags: 12.04, directory, restore

I have lost my back ups on my external hard drive. I think I accidentally deleted the back ups. Possibly using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>, I am not sure.

I have searched online for tools that restore data, but the ones I found could be install on windows and mac computers, and mine is Ubuntu.

Is there any tool that can help me?
Please keep in mind I am not extremely knowledgeable about computers and I am trying to learn.

I would appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try some Data Recovery tools which may help you to restore some of your old data.

[From R-tools Technology:](http://download.cnet.com/windows/R-tools%20Technology/3260-20_4-80773-1.html)

> R-Linux is a free data recovery and undelete utility for Ext2FS/3FS
>   (Linux) file systems. File recovery after power failure, system crash,
>   virus infection, or partition reformation, even for the different file
>   system. Unformat and unerase tool. The utility creates image files an
>   entire disk, partition or its part. Such drive image can be processed
>   like regular drive

You can [download 64 bit verion from here](http://download.cnet.com/R-Linux-Free-Recovery/3000-2248_4-10075543.html).

To install

```
sudo dpkg -i rli_en*.deb
```

Comment: Maythux I tried the tool you suggested it was taking hours to create image, scan and then I was on the recover stage and my computer crashed.. I think it somehow finished the space on my computer and now I get an error image about low graphics and can't log in. I am very frustrated, again I've been searching online but none of the answers seems to work. (Now in tears, browsing from my phone). What can I do now?

Comment: This tool has no effect on system crash. Anyway try to ask a question including errors you have in crash and you'll get help from this site

Answer (score 0):

you can also use gparted's "attempt data rescue" option.

just install gparted if it isnt already installed

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

then run it (from dash or terminal, whatever), enter your password when it prompts you, select your hard drive from the drop down box in the top right corner, and  then go to device> attempt data rescue from the menus top left.